# Do I need to annotate all pictures in the image?

Tags: annotations, labelimg

I've started annotating using LabelImg tool and drawing boxes but I have too many pictures in the images (like lots of grapes in the image). For better trained model, is it required to box all pictures or is it okay to leave some?

I am trying to train a Faster RCNN model.

example:
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as long as it's not getting too small `bbox` and, visually recognizable to the human, or possible to get features within it - that's fine.

For example let's consider the following cases, a [dataset](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/POREXF) contains such meaningless annotation (red marked) which normally an engineer would skip those bounding boxes (`box['w'] * box['h']`) < some threshold.

[image]

Comment: Line in your image, my image has no depth. You see all images clearly

Comment: Do you mean in your image, all objects look clearly?

Comment: In that case, yes, it needs to be annotated as much as possible.

Comment: Added the picture. thanks. Do you think I can skip partially hidden one? We have lots of pictures to annotate. :-(

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, I think you can skip the partial one. The object looks similar, so the trained model should recognize such an object.

Comment: follow-up question. If I train a model with 250x250 images, can I use the model to infer bigger images, for example 500x500?

Comment: The test image need to be preprocessed same as evaluation time. So its better to resize image.